# Prevent Flatlist refreshing when a checkbox is checked

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

So i have multiple checkboxes in a flatlist with nested json .The problem im facing is i have a counter for each element in the nested flatlist and the flatlist refreshes(in turn counter also refreshes) whenever I check a checkbox ,is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong ,I am a beginner and needed some advice

```
const padZero = (num) => {
  return String(num).padStart(2, "0");
};

const NewOrders = () => {


  const [fetchedData, setfetchedData] = useState(orders);
  const [checkedArr, setcheckedArr] = useState([]);


  const CountUpTimer = ({ start }) => {
    const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState(start);
    const [countUp, setcountUp] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const currentDate = new Date(moment().utc("+5:30").toISOString());
        const timeDifference = Math.abs(currentDate - startDate) / 1000; // Time difference in seconds
        const hours = Math.floor(timeDifference / 3600);
        const minutes = Math.floor((timeDifference % 3600) / 60);
        const seconds = Math.floor(timeDifference % 60);

        const formattedTime = `${padZero(hours)}:${padZero(minutes)}:${padZero(
          seconds
        )}`;
        setcountUp(formattedTime);
      }, 1000);

      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }, [startDate]);

    return (
      <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h3, fontWeight: 600, color: COLORS.lightGray6 }}>
        {countUp}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  const checkboxHandler = (orderId, subId, id) => {
    const x = orderId + "-" + subId + "-" + id;

    if (checkedArr.indexOf(x) > -1) {
      let filteredArray = checkedArr.filter((item) => item !== x);
      setcheckedArr(filteredArray);
    } else {
      setcheckedArr([...checkedArr, x]);
    }
  };


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <FlatList
        vertical
        scrollEnabled={true}
        pagingEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={fetchedData}
        extraData={fetchedData}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 14 }}>
              {item.orderList.map((v, i) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <View>
                      {v.orders.map((items, i) => {
                        return (
                          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                            <Checkbox
                              style={{
                                borderColor: "red",
                              }}
                              value={
                                checkedArr.indexOf(
                                  item.orderId +
                                    "-" +
                                    v.orderSubId +
                                    "-" +
                                    items.id
                                ) > -1
                              }
                              onValueChange={() =>
                                checkboxHandler(
                                  item.orderId,
                                  v.orderSubId,
                                  items.id
                                )
                              }
                              color={
                                checkedArr.indexOf(
                                  item.orderId +
                                    "-" +
                                    v.orderSubId +
                                    "-" +
                                    items.id
                                ) > -1
                                  ? "red"
                                  : null
                              }
                            />
                            <View>
                              <Text>{items.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <CountUpTimer start={new Date(v.orderTime)} />
                          </View>
                        );
                      })}
                    </View>
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        }}
        ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 120 }}></View>}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Please refer to the code here [code sandbox here](https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/grumpy-pizza)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behaviour you're observing is normal due to the way React handles re-renders. When you're updating the state (in your case `checkedArr`), the component re-renders, and all child components within it also re-render by default. In your case, this includes the counter.

To solve this issue, there are a couple of strategies you could consider:

1. React.memo: You can use React.memo to wrap your CountUpTimer component. React.memo is a higher order component that memoizes the rendered output, then skips unnecessary renderings if the props are the same.

```
const CountUpTimer = React.memo(({ start }) => {
  //...
});
```

1. Store the timers in state: Instead of starting a new timer every time CountUpTimer is rendered, you could start all the timers when your component is initially rendered and store them in a state variable. This way, the timers won't be reset every time a checkbox is checked. However, this would be a more complex solution and might require significant changes to your code.

While these methods can prevent unnecessary re-renders, they can't guarantee that a child component will never re-render. If a parent component's render method returns a different tree of React elements, the child component will still be re-rendered.

Comment: thanks for the response , I have used Memo in the snack but it still refreshes ,anything im doing wrong ,can you take a look at this snack https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/grumpy-pizza